# How can I get pg_regress?

Tags: postgresql, regression-testing

From [online documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/extend-pgxs.html), it seems that that there is a `pg_regress` program/component for regression tests.

```
REGRESS_OPTS

    additional switches to pass to **pg_regress**
```

I can do simple regression tests (under postgresql coming from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), but couldn't find the program `pg_regress` itself or see its options.

```
$ pg_regress
pg_regress: command not found
```

`which pg_regress` returns empty.

Do I need to install additional packages to get `pg_regress` or is it hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pg_regress` is available from the [source code repository](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git). If you installed PostgreSQL through a package manager or as a binary, it will not be included. Regression testing is typically done after you build the code yourself, for instance with a new release.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, the pakcage [postgresql-server-dev-9.5](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/postgresql-server-dev-9.5) has the `pg_regress` but it's not in the path.
You can find it at: `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/pgxs/src/test/regress/pg_regress`

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to see what options `pg_regress` offers. The simplest way I found was to add the `-h` option to the Makefile of the library/extension you're building. Like:

```
REGRESS_OPTS = "-h"
```

Then doing `make installcheck` will show the options.